# Trocar a view welcome por outra no laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Pretendo trocar a view welcome por outra que criei com um controller. Para melhor compreensão, aqui vai minha tentativa que não está resultando:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/portal', 'portal\SiteController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getPostsCarousel() //Busca os posts para o carousel
{
    return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
}

public function getPostsSite() //Busca os posts que ficam abaixo do carousel
{
    return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get();
}
```

**SiteController**

```
public function index()
{     

    return view('portal.home')
        ->with('postCarousel', $this->getPostsCarousel())
        ->with('postsSite', $this->getPostsSite());
}
```

**view home**

```html
@extends('portal.welcome')

@section('conteudo')
    <div>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-home" data-ride="carousel">


            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                @foreach($postCarousel as $postCar)
                    {{--<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{$i}}"></li>--}}
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' :'' }}"></li>
                @endforeach
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                @foreach($postCarousel as $item)
                    <div class="item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <img src="{{$item->imagem}}" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(133,178,0,0.7)">
                            <p><h3>{{$item->titulo}}</h3></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach

            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="homeNotic">
            <hr>

            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($postsSite as $key =>$value)

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">

                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{$value->imagem}}" alt="{{$value->titulo}}">
                        <div class="noticia-titulo-home" >
                            <p class="titVisualizado"><b>{{$value->titulo}}</b></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="noticia-conteudo-home">
                            <p class="contVisualizado">{{$value->descricao}}</p>
                        </div>


                        <div class="caption" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" >
                            <p>
                                <a href="{{url('visualizar-noticia/'.$value->id)}}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Ler Mais</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="caption" style="height: 25px; padding: 5px" >
                            <p>
                                <span class="pull-right" style="color: #e38d13">{{$value->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                    @endforeach


                    <p>
                        <a style="width: 100%; font-size: 14pt" href="{{url('index-noticia')}}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">VER MAIS NOTÍCIAS <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></a>
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

E estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

Também já tentei alterar a rota para:

```
Route::get('/', function (){
   return view('portal.home');
});
```

E deu o seguinte erro:

> **ErrorException in 2574245cf5e2373fc28372419f83853770ad5aae.php line 8: Undefined variable: postCarousel (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GEIGRE_WEB5_3\resources\views\portal\home.blade.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a um breve check list para utilizar views no laravel.

- Por padrão as views ficam nas pasta `resources/views`
- A chamada de uma view deve ser separada por `.`, logo, para a chamada `view('portal.home')` o seguinte arquivo deve existir neste path `resources/views/portal/home.blade.php`

**Importante** Se seu controller está em uma subpasta de `App\Http\Controllers` você precisa ajustar 2 coisas:

1. Ajustar a declaração do namespace neste controller para refletir essa estrutura de pastas.  Caso contrário o autoload do `composer` não o encontrará o arquivo.
2. Você deve importar o controller base `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` através da declaração `use` logo após o namespace desse arquivo.

Nota: O passo 2 descrito acima é somente obrigatório para controllers que não estão no mesmo nível do arquivo `App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`;

O exemplo abaixo descreve o resumo de um controller no caminho `App/Http/Controllers/Portal`:

```php
<?php
// Este arquivo deverá estar dentro de pasta Portal em App/Http/Controllers
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Portal;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {     
        return view('portal.home', [
            'postCarousel' => $this->getPostsCarousel(),
            'postsSite' => $this->getPostsSite()
        ]);
    }

    public function getPostsCarousel() //Busca os posts para o carousel
    {
        return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    }

    public function getPostsSite() //Busca os posts que ficam abaixo do carousel
    {
        return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get();
    }
}
```

O arquivo de rotas deverá ser o seguinte:

```php
Route::get('portal', 'Portal\SiteController@index');`
```

Após isso você pode executar os seguintes comandos (cmd ou bash) na raíz do seu projeto
 `composer dump-autoload` e `php artisan route:clear` para refazer a estrutura do autoload do composer com o(s) novo(s) namespace(s) e limpar o cache das rotas respectivamente.

Estrutura do projeto:

```
root
├── app
│   ├── Http
│   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   │   ├── Portal
│   │   │   │   ├── SiteController.php
│   │   │   ├── Controller.php
├── resources
│   ├── views
│   │   ├── portal
│   │   │   ├── home.blade.php
```

Sobre o erro:

> ErrorException in 2574245cf5e2373fc28372419f83853770ad5aae.php line 8:
>   Undefined variable: postCarousel (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GEIGRE_WEB5_3\resources\views\portal\home.blade.php)

É devido o seu template estar tentando utilizar as dados que não foram passados para view dentro do clousure. `$postCarousel`